# Add a <li> tag in jquery wont work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

here is my table:

```
<ul class="vertical-tabs-list">
  <li class="vertical-tab-button first selected">blah</li>
  <li class="vertical-tab-button">blah</li>
</ul>
```

I want to append another li like so: 
`$(".vertical-tabs-list").append('<li><input type="submit" name="op" id="edit-save" value="Save" class="form-submit"</li>');`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try closing the `input` tag: `/></li>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$("ul.vertical-tabs-list").append('<li><input type="submit" name="op" id="edit-save" value="Save" class="form-submit" /></li>');
```

This has HTML with no syntax errors and a more specific selector. If that doesn't work check to make sure you have jquery properly linked up with your page.

Also, are you using a document ready function?

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    //your code here
    $("ul.vertical-tabs-list").append('<li><input type="submit" name="op" id="edit-save" value="Save" class="form-submit" /></li>');
});
```

Comment: Yup I have a `console.log` that prints soo I am not sure what is going on

Comment: Console.log will run outside of a doc ready. Make sure you code is wrapped in a document ready handler... should look like the above edit..